# How to pass one element's value into another element's event handler in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm new to learning the DOM manipulations in JS and I've come across passing mostly, a single argument to the event handler's function, like `getSum(this)`. Let's say we have a simple addition function in the script tag, I've included those input elements inside the form, like this which is okay:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="operands" oninput="getSum(this)">
            <input id="op1" type="number" name="op1" placeholder="op1">
            <input id="op2" type="number" name="op2" placeholder="op2">
        </form>
        <p id="output"></p>
        <script>
            function getSum(form_input){
                form_input = document.getElementById("operands").elements;
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = 
                    Number(form_input.namedItem("op1").value) + 
                    Number(form_input.namedItem("op2").value);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to rewrite so that I can eliminate the use of form element, since there are only 2 child elements (input tags) within and pass both elements values in the second one like `getSum([], this)` like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="number" id="op1" name="op1" placeholder="op1">
        <input type="number" id="op2" name="op2" placeholder="op2" oninput="getSum(*[op1's value]*, this)">
        <p id="output"></p>
        <script>
            function getSum(a, b){
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = (Number(a.value) + Number(b.value));
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I pass the first input element's value to the `getSum(a, b)` function as argument a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the listener in the `<script>` instead, and watch for `input` events on the `document.body`. Then you can select both inputs inside the body with `querySelectorAll` (or whatever other method you want), get the values of each, and display their sum:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('input', () => {
  const [aValue, bValue] = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')]
    .map(input => Number(input.value));
  document.getElementById("output").textContent = aValue + bValue;
});
```

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="op1">
<input type="number" placeholder="op2">
<p id="output"></p>
```

While you could *technically* slightly tweak your original code by using `getElementById` in the inline handler, inline handlers should be avoided in almost all cases:

```
<input type="number" id="op1" name="op1" placeholder="op1" oninput="getSum(document.querySelector('#op2'), this)">
<input type="number" id="op2" name="op2" placeholder="op2" oninput="getSum(document.querySelector('#op1'), this)">
```

Comment: Yep, see my answer for a working modification to your current code, but you shouldn't use inline handlers as @CertainPerformance mentions.

Answer (score 1):

You would do generally do this inside of JavaScript rather than on the HTML.

Something like this

```
function getSum() {
  let op2Value = document.getElementById('op2').value;
  let op1Value = document.getElementById('op1').value;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = (Number(op1Value) + Number(op2Value));
}
```

```
<input type="number" id="op1" name="op1" placeholder="op1">
<input type="number" id="op2" name="op2" placeholder="op2" oninput="getSum()">
```